# How to test pandas DataFrame with current timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing

I am going to test *my_function()* which returns a pandas DataFrame with a "utc_timestamp" column. This column contains the current timestamp.

```
def my_function():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, pd.datetime.utcnow()]], columns=['value', 'utc_timestamp'])
```

How can I define a unit test to test the expected output of *my_function()*. Obviously the following approach would not work, because the current timestamp in the test function is not equal to the timestamp when the dataframe was created.

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    df_out = my_function()
    df_expected = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, pd.datetime.utcnow()]], columns=['value', 'utc_timestamp'])
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df_out, df_expected)

>> AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="utc_timestamp") are different
```

Which one is the most professional, most pythonic and most pandas-way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have figured out a way to unit test but here is a way of unit testing your DataFrame...

You must patch the *pd.datetime.utcnow* function and set it to return a static date. Then, you can use an assert statement to check if the two DataFrames are equal.

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
from unittest.mock import patch
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

with patch('pandas.datetime.utcnow', return_value="2020-08-16 20:36:06.578174"):
              actual = my_function()
              expected = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, "2020-08-16 20:36:06.578174"]], columns=['value', 'utc_timestamp'])
              assert_frame_equal(actual, expected)
```

Comment: Oh that a nice solution! I didnt know about the patch utility.